# How add terraform variables in a JSON file

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, terraform, grafana, terraform-provider-aws

Hey team I’m having trouble finding in the documentation on how to add terraform variables in a JSON file,

I need inject this variable in this JSON,

[image]

In this JSON of this shape but not it works,

[image]

I did try with var and locals, I tried it with var and locals, but it does not work, it is by default

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `templatefile` function [1]:

```
locals {
  mystring = "Test"
}

resource "grafana_dashboard" "metrics" {
  config_json = templatefile("${path.root}/EC2.json.tpl", {
    mystring = local.mystring
  })
}
```

For this to work, you would have to change the JSON to be:

```json
"datasource": {
  "type": "CloudWatch"
  "uid": "${mystring}" 
}
```

The file with JSON data should also be renamed to `EC2.json.tpl`.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile